# Sqflite rawQuery not working on real Samsung device

Tags: android, flutter, samsung-mobile, sqflite

I have a rawQuery to sum and sort the database before it is loaded into ListView. This works fine in Android Emulator. However, when I connect my Samsung device and run the same, the Order By part does not work on it.

Below is my rawQuery from my DatabaseProvider :

```
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getsumTotal() async{
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT $colTCategory, $colTMaincat, $colTSubcat, SUM($colTranAmount), $colTranDate FROM $transTable GROUP BY $colAccId ORDER BY $colAccId' );
    return result;
  }
```

I am calling this in a Stateful widget using a Future Builder and use Card - List Tile:

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> sumTotal()async{
    final transMap = await databaseProvider.getsumTotal();
    tranMap = transMap;
    return transMap;
  }

      body: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: sumTotal(),
        //future: getSumTrans(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading..');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              else
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: tranMap.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.category),
                            title: Text(tranMap[i]['tmaincat'].toString()),
                            trailing:
                                Text(tranMap[i]['SUM(tranamount)'].toString()),
                            subtitle: Text(
                                (tranMap[i]['tsubcat']).toString()),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                          //child: Text(header[i]['tmaincat'].toString() ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
          }
        },
      )),
```

While the sum function works fine in the connected device, the order by function does not.

I have even built the apk and tried this with no result.

Any inputs as to what could be wrong?

Regards
GP

Comment: *"the order by function does not."* how do you know that? what if you (just for testing) add `$colAccId` to your select list and `print(result)` before calling `return result`?

Comment: You are right @pskink. Obviously the database in the android device was different from the laptop version and hence the ordering was different. Thanks,  it is working fine.